# Can we choose to go in to chat when comments grow?

Tags: support, comments

Usually when comments keep on adding the system suggests to take it up on chat. But this didn't happen with one question recently. Shouldn't the users be able to opt to chat when it is necessary? Or is there already a way to tackle this?

Answer (score 1):

The offer only actually appears when two people are ABABing for a while. If there's more than two people exchanging comments, the option doesn't appear.

It *would* be nice if we could invite people to chat earlier, and there might be a feature request for that.

> Shouldn't the users be able to opt to chat when it is necessary? Or is there already a way to tackle this?

You can create a custom chat room and invite people there, i.e. doing the process manually. However, the comments won't get copied into that chat room.

Comment: It is just 2 people. But I guess the phase was very low and that's why it didn't trigger.